# AMD Dual GPU Issue

Tags: graphics, amd, radeon

I'm new to eOS. Sorry for my probably bad english, i'm french ^^".

When I'm trying to watch videos (personal videos or youtube), the screen is in a strange red style.

[image]

If the quality is very low (like 240p) i can watch without this effect.

After many hours of research, the problem is probably because my PC has 2 gpu, and use the wrong one. Or because of old drivers.

Here some terminal commands i found on topics

[image]
[image]

As you can see on the second one, I have a Radeon R7 which, i think, is not used.

Do you know what i have to do ? How can i change the gpu used ? Or which driver i have to install ?

Comment: Please check [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) article from linuxconfig. I think you better check the original article there as it will be so huge to add here as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot ! I did many research (and re-install ^^") before seeing your answer... and i found a solution which, i think, is interesting

When you're installing Elementary OS, he ask if you want to 
"Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware, Flash, MP3 and other media".

That's the "problem". Without this checked, i had no problems for graphics.

I was happy until the moment I would install another thing. It was the`ubuntu-restricted-extras` package. And then the problem was here again.

I think it's an installation called when you tick the checkbox before (confirmation ?)

So i installed `synaptic`, and i removed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` (and `ubuntu-restricted-addons` also).

The problem was always here but with `sudo apt-get autoremove` and a reboot, it was OK. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

install the latest MESA drivers, add the official repositories and them open terminal and do:

1º `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

2º `sudo apt install software-properties-common`

3º `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates`

4º `sudo apt update`

5º `sudo apt upgrade`

6º `sudo apt install libvulkan1 mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils`

They work very well, even in games. if u want privative drivers i have a video for install privative drivers: https://youtu.be/_zDLT9wQHmU (only if open drivers do not work)

You will also try to install video codec:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

source:

https://translate.google.cl/translate?hl=es-419&sl=es&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muylinux.com%2F2017%2F03%2F28%2Fubuntu-ppa-mesa%2F

https://www.muylinux.com/2017/03/28/ubuntu-ppa-mesa/