# how to make AMD switchable graphics work in linux?

Tags: release-juno, graphic-drivers, amd

I do have AMD redeon 530 graphics card in my laptop. Is there a way i can make PC to use it.MY steam doesnt detect my AMD redeon 530 graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific on what hardware do you have. In my case i follow [this](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Installing-drivers) guide for my laptop and amd hardware.
It will be good to read [this thread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18085/amd-dual-gpu-issue) but don't follow instructions blindly, its purely informatively.

My laptop is [Lenovo Z50-75](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Lenovo-Z50-75-RAM-upgrade-OS-Linux/td-p/4335214).